# How to get the harmonics of ZZTop?

Tags: technique, electric-guitar, harmonics

I'm a right-handed newbie, so bear with me.  When Gibbons plays in his groove, harmonics seem to be immediate as he picks.  Many times I don't hear the note itself and the harmonics ***is*** the primary sound.  ' Not talking about a similar effect at the 5th, 7th, or 12th fret where it's naturally ready to occur with the perfect left-hand finger lightly on the string and then picking an octave higher

I accidentally found a setting on my amp with a multi-effects RP-1 pedal but stupidly changed the settings before I noted how it happened.

Can anyone tell me how to start a trial and error method or otherwise to locate this effect again?  My own attempts have been futile.

Thanks!

Comment: Gibbons almost always uses pinch harmonics. We have a question on pinch harmonics here with some simple explanation which looks like 100% dupe. I think I'll close as dupe and merge - the answers all look appropriate: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/1394/104